# How to create tar file like this?

Tags: terminal, tar, ls

I need to create a .tar file `testDay00`. When I run the command `ls -1`, the output should look like this

[image]

Comment: The command you need is `ls -l` (lower-case `L`), not `ls -1` (digit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what your problem is (other then the listing command is ls -l (not ls -1)

To create a target file use a command like

```
tar -cf testDay00 /path/to/files/to/compression
```

You can then change permissions with

```
chmod 455 testDay00
chown login.wheel testDay00
```